# How to parse page numbers like print preview does using Regex

Tags: php, regex

If you want to print arbitrary pages on windows/office you can define it like in the picture:

[image]

So, this will print pages: `1,2,3,6,7,8`

Now, I'm trying to do same thing using Regex

```
<?php
$str = "1-4,6,7,8";

        preg_match('/((\d+-\d+)|(\d+)),((\d+-\d+)|(\d+))/',$str,$out);

        print_r($out);
?>
```

and it prints

```
Array ( [0] => 1-4,6 [1] => 1-4 [2] => 1-4 [3] => [4] => 6 [5] => [6] => 6 )
```

but I want to is the following

```
Array ( [0] => 1-4 [1] => 6, [2] => 7, [3] => 7 )
```

How can I do this?

Here is the [fiddle](http://codepad.viper-7.com/2nmtEH)

Comment: Why do that with regex? It's very easy with `explode()` by comma and then handling each part (with check if it's number or interval)

Comment: Yes, `explode` is a better solution for it

Comment: Well, simply I didn't think of that. Explode also does the job. But I asked question for Regex and accepting M42's answer. Thanks @Victor

Comment: explode will execute more fast than regex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this:

```
$str = "1-4,6,7,8";
preg_match_all('/(\d+(?:-\d+)?),?/', $str, $out);
print_r($out);
```

**output:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1-4,
            [1] => 6,
            [2] => 7,
            [3] => 8
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1-4
            [1] => 6
            [2] => 7
            [3] => 8
        )

)
```

Answer (score 3):

Check this regexp pattern, please

```
$str = "1-4,6,7,8";

preg_match('/((\d+-\d+)|(\d+)),?/',$str,$out);

print_r($out);
```

or better use `explode` function:

```
$str = "1-4,6,7,8";

$out = explode(',', $str);

print_r($out);
```

Comment: Thanks Victor, a nice alternative to regex and maybe better. BTW, this doesn't guarantee hyphens. If users enters like `1=4,6,7,8` by accident I should handle it later.

Comment: Ok, I understand now what you want )

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

`(\d+)-?(\d*)?(,(?!$))?`

---

1. Matches 1 or more numbers (mandatory).
2. Optional match for hyphen.
3. Optional match for second set of digits.
4. Optional comma after each set of numbers but does not allow comma on the end.

---

[**DEMO**](http://regex101.com/r/xA6tR6)